# How to use cordova with angular 2 without Ionic

Tags: cordova, angular

Trying to build a cordova app using angular 2.

I did not use Ionic2 to build the app, is there any way to use cordova and its plugins anyways?

What would import from in my Angular2 Service?

i.e.:

```
import { What } from 'which-source?';
```

Comment: did you try something? Your post looks strange without `ionic build` how you will create and launch a dummy application first?

Comment: Create 1 cordova application, create 1 angular 2 application, Copy all the transpiled src in cordovas www

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering for the week-end it was actually pretty simple:

All I really had to do was typings install type definition for cordova and it's plugins.  In my case:

> npm install cordova typings -g
>
> typings install dt~cordova dt~cordova-plugin-file dt~cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save --global
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file cordova-plugin-file-transfer

So long as you initialize your angular2 app on 'deviceready' cordova will be available.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
},
```

After which intellisense and cordova work like a dream.

Comment: Hi, Please give solution for my issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343585/3600674

Comment: what dt~ means ?

Comment: @Amirjohn it's DefinitelyTyped a collection of definitions for different libraries

Comment: with your accepted solution I got an idea to add plugins through typings but when I cal the plugin it errors as undefined. Is any this I need to added in my project

Comment: Did you "cordova plugin add your-plugin-name"?  You need to do this to actually install the plugins not just tell typescript how to use them.

Comment: Glad to hear it, I've updated the answer with the extra step

Comment: Now Its working for  me with following steps (1.Created Angular project, 2.Create cordova project 3.Called cordova plugin in project 4.Copied build files into cordova project 5.Decleared my pluing in .ts file header(because I got error as function not defined in .ts) file. 6.Ran the cordova project its works. but without using the typings its works. Is anything wrong or any future problem may it cause?

Comment: As said above decleared my plugin in .ts file header in the sense added this line  'declare var device;' below import lines. I used device pluing for my case it warned cannot find device in .ts files