# Cordova application using Angular 2

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

Instead of ionic I would like to use cordova framework.

So far,

**Step 1:**

I have created an angular 2 application.

**Step 2:**

I have created an cordova application and integrated angular 2 application in it.

Its running successfully.

**Step 3:**

Next step is to load cordova.js file on load

**Step 4:**

Add cordova plugin(like camera , device ext) in my project.

Step 1 and 2  completed.

Please help me out to complete **step 3 and step 4**.

When I call plugin its throws an error as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add any Cordova plugin in agular project,

1. Edit main.ts to look like this:

   if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
   }
   let onDeviceReady = () => {
     platformBrowserDynamic()
     .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
     .catch(err => console.error(err));

   };
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
2. For any plugin(for example Camera):
   on top,
   declare let navigator: any;

   use:
   navigator.camera.getPicture(success, failure, { quality: 80 });
   .
3. In index.html of the angular project add the following script.

   `<script type="application/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`
   Note: The MIME type should be "application/javascript"  not "text/javascript".
4. Build the project using the command

   ng build --base-href . --prod  --output-path ./Aditya/www/
   Note: here Aditya is name of the cordova project
5. Now edit the index.html file inside Aditya/www/ folder of Cordova project to 
   include MIME for all the script included.

   **type="application/javascript"**
6. Now you are good to go.

Answer (score 9):

Got an output with following steps,

1)Created an angular project

(Optional)I am using the [angular IDE](https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/) to create angular project

2)Added reference to cordova.js file reference in angular project html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

3)Create an cordova project

4)Added platform and plugin to the cordova project.

for my case I added browser platform and cordova device plugin.

5)In angular project implemented OnIt and added the plugin callback function as follow.

**Note:** It is important to call cordova plugin after '**onDeviceReady**'

```
    import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    ngOnInit() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
           alert(device.platform);
        }
    }

    }
```

6)Typescript does not recogonise '**device.platform**' and warns as **cannot find device**

To resolve this issue add the line '**declare var device;**'

After adding the above my AppComponent.ts file looks like follows,

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var device;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
           alert(device.platform);
        }
}

}
```

7)Build the angular project and copy the build files into cordova /www folder

I am using the script to copy file from angular project to cordova. [Tutorial here](https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2)

8)Prepare and run the cordova project.

for my case I ran the cordova project in browser and got an alert with value 'Browser'

Comment: Have you tried it with https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps? Spent 3 days on this still can't get it to understand what `plugin` is. I'll give you massive thumbs up if you could help me out.

Comment: Where should  create cordova project (point number 3), u mean inside the angular project??

Comment: Create the cordova project seperately

Comment: Here you will not able to access 'this' inside onDeviceReady.

Answer (score 1):

When are you calling the plugin - are you waiting for onDeviceReady to fire?

Comment: Hi MStoner, So far I have not waited for ondevice ready,i  will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an official solution but you can bootstrap your angular 2,4 with onDeviceReady event listener on `maint.ts` and then all your application will run when event is fired. Ex:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
 }, false);
```